# adding new line to Metro Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, newline

I use the MetroFramework for my gui
but I have a problem with adding new lines to my MetroTextbox
I've tried

\n\r

\r\n

\r

\n

Environment.NewLine

And MultiLine = true

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it
but I suppose it should not be done this way

```
private List<string> Lines = new List<string>();
        public void WriteLog(string LogString)
        {
            if (this.ServerLogTextbox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback Recal = new SetTextCallback(WriteLog);
                this.Invoke(Recal, new object[] {LogString});
            }
            else
            {
                Lines.Add("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss") + "]: " + LogString);
                ServerLogTextbox.Lines = Lines.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `AppendText()` as follow

```
            metroTextBox1.Multiline = true;
            metroTextBox1.Size = new Size(300, 50);

            metroTextBox1.Text = "";
            metroTextBox1.AppendText("Line1");
            metroTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            metroTextBox1.AppendText("Line2");
```